# Capture image into three ImageViews

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

On the same Activity, I have three cards, each with an ImageButton and an ImageView that look like this: 
[image]

When the camera button is pressed, I'd like the camera to take a picture and assign the image taken to that particular ImageView. 
What I have so far is this:

I created an OnTouchEventListener for each button like so:

```
ImageButton camera1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera_button1);
        camera1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // action started modify alpha
                        v.setAlpha((float)0.5);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        // touch ended modify alpha back
                        // Toast.makeText(context, "Touch ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        v.setAlpha((float)1.0);

                        // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        //intent.putExtra("imageViewName", "front");

                        //bundle.putString("camera1", "front");
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("camera1", "front");

                        // start the image capture Intent
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Neither, using intent.putExtra("test", "test"); or intent.putExtra(bundle) work. My reasoning behind adding a string to each intent is to be able to use that string as a flag and in:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Bundle bundle = null;
                bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

                // Get the bundle and extract strings
                String test = bundle.getString("camera1");

                // Create a thumbnail
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                // Detect where to assign the view
                switch ((String)data.getExtras().get("imageViewName")) {

                    case "front":
                        front.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;
                    case "message":
                        message.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;
                    case "address":
                        address.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;
                    case "other1":
                        other1.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;
                    case "other2":
                        other2.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;
                    case "other3":
                        other3.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user

            }
        }

        // Get the return data from the camera

    }
```

try to catch that intent and choose to what ImageView to assign the image pushed from the camera. So basically, I'd like to be able when the user clicks on ImageView1's button to have the image coming back from the camera to attached to that ImageView. How do I handle that?

Comment: have you try to use three different requestCode ,and handle it onActivityResult?

Comment: @davidleen29, I have not. That's actually a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OPTION ONE:**

Pass different constants to your camera activity, like

```
startActivityForResult(it, REQ_SCAN + imgIndex);
```

and just catch it in your

```
 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
    switch (request) {
      case REQ_SCAN + 0: 
      case REQ_SCAN + 1: 
      case REQ_SCAN + 2:  break;
      imgIndex = request - REQ_SCAN;
    }
   ...
```

The three different values should uniquely identify your pictures as you requested them.

**OPTION TWO:**

When firing the camera, create a temp file with a unique name, hand it to the camera and keep the name around.

```
      tmpFl = File.createTempFile(TMP_FILENM, null, context.getExternalCacheDir());
      it.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tmpFl));
        startActivityForResult(it, REQ_SCAN);
        mTmpFlNm = tmpFl.getAbsolutePath();
      }
```

And when it comes back in 'onActivityResult()'

```
  case REQ_SCAN: {
    if (result == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      try {
        tmpFl = new File(mTmpFlNm);
        byte[] jpgBuff = UT.file2Bytes(tmpFl));
      } finally { if (tmpFl != null) tmpFl.delete(); }
    }
    break;
```

just grab the temp file you handed to the cam activity, get it's content (it is a buffer with jpg data) and decompress it to a bitmap (or do other stuff with it - upload, rename, save...).

So, in your case, you would probably play with 3 different file names. OPTION ONE is probably more elegant for your needs.

Good Luck

Comment: thanks @seanpj, this is definitely something I can work with. up-voted.

Comment: @seanpj: would you kindly edit your answer, so that the UPDATE be the primary one, and the obscure file-driven solution will not tempt innocent people to do crazy things.

Comment: @AlexCohn  Cleaned it up, but left both solutions, since they may useful.